# VBA object SpeakXML True

Tags: vba, object, wav, speech

I'm trying to make an Excel Macro to speak the value in certain cells and record it into a wav file.

I'm struggling to set SpeakXML true so that I can add long pauses inbetween certain words.

```
Set oFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
oFileStream.Format.Type = SAFT48kHz16BitStereo

fileRouteName = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test\" & "TESTfile" & ".wav"
oFileStream.Open fileRouteName, SSFMCreateForWrite

SayThis = Cells(1, 1).Value

Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Set oVoice.AudioOutputStream = oFileStream

oVoice.Speak SayThis

oFileStream.Close
```

Cell(1,1) has the written text : Wait for long pause < silence msec="20000"/> this is the end

Comment: What is your current problem? How does the output/result differ from your expectation? NB: You may need to [specify the optional flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720892%28v%3dvs.85%29) `SVSFIsXML` to the Speak method so it knows to parse the XML. E.g., `oVoice.Speak SayThis, SVSFIsXML + SVSFlagsAsync`, however, your input string isn't strictly XML so I am not sure this will work, but you should try it.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it, by just adding the number 8 as you suggested, it understood the xml tag <silence> written in the cell.